# Is it possible to amplify AC signal with In Amp in Single Supply?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

Is it possible to amplify AC signal with In Amp in Single Supply, however, with a sufficient reference to 'compensate' the negative part of the signal?

I believe that a in amp with a single supply, for example 5V and GND, can not amplify negative signals because the power is not symmetrical. Right? Or not?

**My point is:**

*If I add a reference (Pin 5) that makes the signal completely positive, is it possible to amplify this signal? Having as a result a fully positive amplified signal?*

I'm using a in amp (INA118) with single supply (GND on pin 4 and 5V on pin 7) with gain equal to 2 (Rg = 50KOhm). On reference pin 5 I'm adding + 2.5V (Vdd / 2).

[image]

In my project, I need to inject a 1mA electric current into the patient's body through 2 electrodes, receive this signal through 2 other electrodes, and amplify this signal. [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV1a7.jpg).
The sine is a sinusoid of 1.98V pp and 1mA (With a frequency sweep from 1KHz to 100KHz) with the voltage ranging from -0.99V to +0.99V. The Schematic is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU6cr.png).

Comment: Can you string the complete diagram together, please: current source,.. patient,.. InAmp?..  Reference electrode, perhaps?..  You are not leaving that to us, are you?

Comment: Nick, The Schematic is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU6cr.png

I will use o AD5933 and a HPF (High pass filter or Capacitor Block DC), in the output of the HPF, the voltage will be 1.98V pp (-0.99V to +0.99V). The current source use two opamps (AD8606 with single supply +5V), the outputs of the current source (E1, E2) are the 2 current eletrodes, Z represent the patient's body, and E3, E4 are the two voltage electrodes. The AD5933 is a Sine wave generator and a ADC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that a in amp with a single supply, for example 5V and GND,
>   can not amplify negative signals because the power is not symmetrical.
>   Right? Or not?

Correct, this won't work. The full range of the input has to be bounded within the power rails of the InAmp. In fact it's a little tighter than this if you look at the [data sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjRnpjO-JbSAhVFtRoKHcIBAFwQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fina118.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFzQBYkEOioJ6H3OrO03gCUMlcpuw&sig2=RLKV7Rs-9O7tlmtjITHsfQ&cad=rja).

If you look on page 5 it tells you the "linear input voltage range" and this is restricted to typically -Vs + 0.95 volts and +Vs - 0.65 volts. In your situation, with a 0V and 5V rail, the input range is +0.95 volts to +4.35 volts. No amount of fiddling with the ref pin is going to alter this.

There are similar restrictions to the output voltage range too.